# MongoDB index need to include "_id" for it to cover if projecting "_id"?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

According to MongoDB Covered query documentation: [Link](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-optimization/#std-label-read-operations-covered-query) ,
for an index `db.inventory.createIndex( { type: 1, item: 1 } )`
projection has to explicitly exclude "_id" for an index to cover the query.
But Index has to have the "_id " for it to tie back to original document.  Does someone know why?

Expecting not to include _id in index as thats not queried on but rather need it in output.

Comment: Your question probably require more information, as I don't get what you mean by Index has to have `_id`. Thinks of index as just a new array (see - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/), which is sorted by the defined field (e.g type, item in this case), and you apply Binary search to jump to the position where you need the data; this just reduces the scope of search. `_id` is anyway indexed automatically.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I meant with Index has to have _id is index created like this (with _id included in index):   db.inventory.createIndex( { type: 1, item: 1 , _id:1 } )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But Index has to have the "_id " for it to tie back to original document.

This claim is not correct. Internally MongoDB uses a `$recordId` field to track and refer to documents. See also [the `.showRecordId()` documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.showRecordId/).

As a result, the `_id` field is *not* included in an index by default. If you would like that information returned to the client (or to filter on it etc.), then you must include it in the index definition. This is the reason for the guidance in the documentation that you referenced.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Do you know why MongoDB uses another $recordId field, while it already has "unique" _id field?